# Datamapper Return Null WSO2

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I have an API that will return XML data, I want to use datamapper to map some data and then return it to the client, but the API after using DataMapper keeps returning null.

see below

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/AllAdByCRN" name="AllAdByCRN" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="POST">
        <inSequence>
            <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                <format>
                    <soapenv:Envelope format="soap11" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                        <soapenv:Header/>
                        <soapenv:Body>
                            <GetCustomerWaselNotCancelled xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
                                <userName></userName>
                                <password></password>
                                <id></id>
                                <idType></idType>
                                <sequenceNumber></sequenceNumber>
                                <laborOffice></laborOffice>
                            </GetCustomerWaselNotCancelled>
                        </soapenv:Body>
                    </soapenv:Envelope>
                </format>
                <args/>
            </payloadFactory>
            <header name="Action" scope="default" value=""/>
            <call>
                <endpoint>
                    <http format="soap11" method="post" uri-template="">
                        <timeout>
                            <duration>17000000</duration>
                            <responseAction>fault</responseAction>
                        </timeout>
                        <suspendOnFailure>
                            <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
                            <progressionFactor>1</progressionFactor>
                        </suspendOnFailure>
                        <markForSuspension>
                            <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                        </markForSuspension>
                    </http>
                </endpoint>
            </call>
            <property expression="json-eval($.*)" name="responseData" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
            <datamapper config="gov:datamapper/NewConfig.dmc" inputSchema="gov:datamapper/NewConfig_inputSchema.json" inputType="JSON" outputSchema="gov:datamapper/NewConfig_outputSchema.json" outputType="XML" xsltStyleSheet="gov:datamapper/NewConfig_xsltStyleSheet.xml"/>
            <log level="custom">
                <property expression="json-eval($.*)" name="responseData"/>
            </log>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

I want to map data only not converting from XML to JSON.

Comment: You haven't shared sufficient information to understand your question. Please provide all the details necessary. For example, Datamapper configs, the response message, what you expect after mapping data etc.

Comment: I choose to do it with JavaScript way . anyway thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to choose XML as input and output :

```
<datamapper config="gov:datamapper/NewConfig.dmc" inputSchema="gov:datamapper/NewConfig_inputSchema.json" inputType="XML" outputSchema="gov:datamapper/NewConfig_outputSchema.json" outputType="XML" xsltStyleSheet="gov:datamapper/NewConfig_xsltStyleSheet.xml"/>
```